# Can I use quick help syntax in C in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

How can I use the quick help syntax ([Quick help syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/ComentBlock.html)) in a C program in Xcode? Something like that:

```
/**
- Returns: 
*/
```

...does not work for me (only in Swift).

Is there any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about block comment in Xcode then follow this.

Select the code you want to comment in Xcode.
Then press Cmd + / .
All lines will be commented.
To uncomment do the same.

Also you can use these syntax in Xcode.

[image]

[image]

Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: My question is not about block comment but about quick help syntax - f.ex., when you alt/option-click on a function/method, you can see quick help. Is that possible in imperative-C?